# css show separator icon for icons

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario like the below to show a spacer(line) before and after icons(Cross symbols) and not to show spacer(line) before and after buttons(with Cancel text). How can I achieve this... [image]

My Css file is

```
.Container > *:first-child::before,
.Container > *::after 
{
    display: inline-block;
    content: url('../Content/Images/Line.png');
}
```

1. All my icons, buttons(with Cancel text) are inside container div
2. Can we restrict showing lines before and after buttons(with Cancel text)?

I tried the below code which did not work.

```
.Container > *:not(input[type="button"]):first-child::before,
.Container > *:not(input[type="button"])::after 
{
    display: inline-block;
    content: url('../Content/Images/Line.png');
}
```

Comment: And what's your HTML? You have > 560 rep (as I write this), you should already know you need to post the relevant code. And what do you mean "*Can we restrict buttons…in container?*"?

Comment: Why use an image anyway for something that looks like it might as well be easily enough achieved by using simple `border`s …?

Comment: Have to use images as color of lines dynamically change. Few line icons images are gradients.

Comment: In your picture there a line before the first button, between the two buttons, and after the second button – now which of those _don’t_ you want? (And, yes – what is your HTML?)

Comment: I am trying to remove those lines with above css. * applies lines before and after each child.

Comment: Which part of "what is your HTML?" is it that's causing you trouble? To answer css problems we often (definitely, in this cas) need to see the HTML you're trying to work with.

Comment: HTML is still needed even with a bounty...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**:

Assuming demo markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <span>x</span>
    <span>x</span>
    <span>x</span>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
    <span>x</span>
    <span>x</span>
    <span>x</span>
</div>
```

.. you could use the following CSS to acheive what you need:

### CSS

```
.container > *:not([type="button"]):first-child::before,
.container > *:not([type="button"])::after 
{
    /*content: url('../Content/Images/Line.png');*/
    content: ''; /* if line image is used, this is not necessary */
    background: #555; /* if line image is used, this is not necessary */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 8px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4TKpm/)**

Side note: Instead of using the `*` selector - you could target the specific child elements, or -even better - add a class name to the child elements

---

**So why didn't your original css - as posted in the question - work?**

The :not() pseudo class can only accept a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

From the spec:

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector,
>   **[attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)**, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

So although the not pseudo class can accept an attribute selector like: `:not([type="button"])`, in your code you have combined it with an element selector  - ie. `input` ---- `:not(input[type="button"])` - which is why the code doesn't work.

So this will work:

```
.Container > *:not([type="button"])::after 
{
    display: inline-block;
    content: url('../Content/Images/Line.png');
}
```

..but this won't:

```
.Container > *:not(input[type="button"])::after 
{
    display: inline-block;
    content: url('../Content/Images/Line.png');
}
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j3Xsp/3/)** to illustrate this.

Comment: Good point but this is working for hiding text and not a line icon.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key to solving your problem is using an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). You can select elements by their preceding sibling as follows:

```css
.sibling#one + .sibling#two {
    /* style every .sibling#two that is preceded by a .sibling#one */
}
```

I've made a quick example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dNtET/3/), using borders instead of the images with lines and div's as buttons. I hope this will help, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the line before and after the icons, instead of using wildcard `*` and then trying to deselect buttons, simply target the icons alone. Assuming the icons has class `.class`

```
.Container > .icon:first-child::before,
.Container > .icon::after 
{
 display: inline-block;
 content: url('../Content/Images/Line.png');
}
```

or if the icons are `<img>`, corresponding css would be

```
.Container > img:first-child::before,
.Container > img::after 
{
 display: inline-block;
 content: url('../Content/Images/Line.png');
}
```

problem solved (*can't be more specific since you haven't provided much information*).